# open ODF file for editing in PHP

Tags: php, odf

I am developing a Document Management System and want to enable user to **open a document for editing**.

I have used `PHPWord` and it does not open a document which user wants to edit.

Currently I am trying with `OpenTBS` and also found no solution to edit document.

From following here [documentation](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php?doc#show)

```
  include_once('tbs_class.php');
  include_once('tbs_plugin_opentbs.php');
    $TBS = new clsTinyButStrong;
    $TBS->Plugin(TBS_INSTALL, OPENTBS_PLUGIN);
    $TBS->LoadTemplate('document.odt');
    $TBS->Show(OPENTBS_FILE);
```

It does nothing, blank page!

Also tried

```
$TBS->Show(OPENTBS_NOHEADER); but nothing happens.
```

One more question, what `header` should I use here as mentioned in documentation?

```
header(...); // your custom headers here
```

Edit:- Suggest any other library for PHP, if there, which can open an ODF document for editing in browser. There is **WebODF** but I have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23355683/how-to-open-document-for-editing-in-webodf) issue with it!

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument_software lists several PHP tools for working with ODT.

- Docvert
- OpenDocumentPHP
- odf-xslt
- OpenDocument
- ods-php
- odtPHP

I haven't used any of these, I'm just giving you the list. You'll have to evaluate them to see if they have the specific features you need.